# .htaccess serving other files if specific files are not found

Tags: .htaccess

If I have /index.html and the user goes to domain.tld or domain.tld/index.html I want them to get that page. (Default behavior)

If I don't have /index.html but I do have /content.txt I'd like to serve the page /makeindex.php but not change the url.

If I don't have /index.html or /content.txt I'd like to serve /nocontent.php but not change the url.

So far I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /makeindex.php [L]
```

But I don't know how to limit this to domain.tld or domain.tld/index.html and I also don't know how I would create that two step process first checking for content.txt if I serve /makeindex.php or falling back to /nocontent.php if both those files don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule, put this at the top of your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if /index.html exists serve it as a directory index and main page
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
#if content.txt exists , use makeindex.php as directory index
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content.txt -f
RewriteRule ^$ /makeindex.php [L]
#else set /nocontent.php as directory index
 RewriteRule ^$ /nocontent.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I modified it to. Don't the [L]s stop all the conditions above it? I'm confused and wondering if I can shorten this some more.

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.html)?\??
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content.txt -f
    RewriteRule ^ makeindex.php [L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\.html)?\??
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content.txt !-f
    RewriteRule ^ nocontent.php [L]